# Android audio mode change notification

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I'd like to know when the audio mode (as returned by [AudioManager.getMode()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#getMode%28%29)) has changed.  This is so that I can disable functionality in my app while the mode is not MODE_NORMAL.  Obviously I can poll but that isn't battery friendly and a waste of CPU.

There is a broadcast intent when a call comes in, but that isn't usable since it also tells you the incoming phone number and I don't want those permissions for my app.  It is likely the mode change may have happened with the user switching to a different app in which case my Activity would know, but there are many other scenarios under which the audio mode could change and I just wouldn't know.

I can't use the AudioFocus stuff from 2.2 as I need to support 1.6 onwards.

Edit: The kind of functionality I want to stop includes shake detection and various timers.  I want to enter a dormant mode on audio mode being non-normal and become active again on MODE_NORMAL.

Comment: did u get an answer?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest a two phased attack.

Use AudioFocus for platforms that it supports. That's something like 90% of phones, so for most users this will provide the best solution. There's no reason your app can't support both implementations and simply provide the one suitable for the underlying platform at runtime.

For 1.6, I'd suggest the following. Presumably the functionality within your app that you want to affect is some sort of audio playback. If your app is in the process of playing back audio, the incremental battery drain of polling to see if the audio mode changes is going to be relatively minor.

When you're not playing back audio, you only need to query the current audio mode before you begin playing back audio.

For the case you specify, the battery impact of listening for sensor changes and running timers is, again, going to dwarf the effect of polling the audio mode -- particularly as you're seeking to enable your functionality whenever the mode is normal.

As your only looking to disable certain functionality for the short periods of time that the phone is in a call, you'd be better off querying the audio mode immediately before performing whatever action you wish to disable while a call is ongoing.

So the steps become:

- Check audio mode before playback / action.
- Poll audio mode during playback.

Comment: I've updated to the question to clarify.  I do do polling during audio playback but that is for short snippets now and then.  It is the rest of the time that I'm concerned about.  The version support is non-negotiable.